# How to check if a variable is Array or Object?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

For deserialising a json object, I had to define a parent class that would contain an object or an array of objects for the child class. It has to be an object if an object was retrieved, or an array of objects if an array was retrieved from the json.

JSON array object

```
{"y":{"x":[{"data":28}, {"data":56}, {"data":89}]}}
```

JSON object

```
{"y":{"x":{"data":28}}}
```

y is receiving x at a time, and x[] at another time. There is no such condition to determine whether y would recieve an array or an object.

Hence for determining whether I received an array or not, I am checking the IsArray() condition.

I tried

```
class Y
{
   public X x { get { return System.IsArray() ? new X() : new x[] }; set; }
}

class X
{
   public int data { get; set; }
}
```

1. It isnt working.
2. System.IsArray() isn't being recognised??

Comment: Do you have control over the logic that generates the JSON? If so you should consider redesigning the data objects to follow a standard contract. Having a property that is sometimes a single object and sometimes an array is a poor design and problematic in the long run. If you have the ability you should just consider making it an array and build your object models to account for that.

Comment: [IsArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx) checks on a `Type`. You should check it on the object you are interested in checking, not on `System`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, an array *is* an object.  That's a good thing, since it allows these functions to work (both assume `using System;`):

```
bool IsArray(object o) { return o is Array; }
bool IsArray(object o) { return o.GetType().IsArray; }
```

Second, if you want a property whose type can be either `X` or `X[]`, the property's type needs to be `object`:

```
class Y             
{
   private object _x;
   public object x {
       get { return _x; }
       set
       {
           if (value.GetType != typeof(X) && value.GetType != typeof(X[]))
               throw new ArgumentException("value");
           _x = value;
       }
   }
}
```

This somewhat ignores the advantage of static typing, as you're using `object` and checking types at run time.  It would really be much simpler to define the property as an array, even for those cases where there's only one value.  In such cases, it would be an array whose length is 1.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) Nuget package, and it's been really easy to work with:

```
  string jsonStr = "{'y':{'x':[{'data':28}, {'data':56}, {'data':89}]}}";
  dynamic jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);

  bool isArray  = jobject.y.x.Type == JTokenType.Array;
  bool isObject = jobject.y.x.Type == JTokenType.Object;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

the property x of Type X in class Y cannot be an array of X if you explicity state it is of type X. Declaring it as an object would be one way to get round this.

If you want to check it is an array I would use a backing field (say _x) and then where you use the property do a check (`typeof(_x) == X[]`)

That could get messy though, my best advice would be set the type of property x to X[] and in the set determine whether the value was an array (if so just set `_x = value`) or if not add value to an empty array of X

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
if (obj.GetType().IsArray)
{
  ...
}
```

Another way you can do it is,

```
if (obj is Array) {
   ...
}
```