# How to check if a JSON output returns 1 or more rows so that either a string or arraylist can be used and mapped accordingly to an object in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, ienumerable

How can I check if a JSON output returned just 1 row of an element or multiple rows.
For example, I have the below JSON output.

```
{
    "orders": {
        "order": [
            {
                "id": 100,
                "type": "market",
                "symbol": "AAPL",
                "side": "buy"
            }]
    }
}
```

I have the below code for deserializing the JSON output:

```
 dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

 Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\n Type: {1}\n Symbol: {2}\n Side: {3}\n", dynObj.orders.order.id, dynObj.orders.order.type,dynObj.orders.order.symbol,dynObj.orders.order.side;
```

But, most of the times I get the output as an array of order object as below

```
 {
        "orders": {
            "order": [
                {
                    "id": 101,
                    "type": "market",
                    "symbol": "AAPL",
                    "side": "buy"
                },
                {
                    "id": 102,
                    "type": "market",
                    "symbol": "MSFT",
                    "side": "buy"
                },
                {
                    "id": 103,
                    "type": "limit",
                    "symbol": "AMZN",
                    "side": "buy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

So I deserialize the above Json output as shown:

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

                    foreach (var c in dynObj.orders.order)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id : {0}\n", c.id);
                        Console.WriteLine("Type : {0}\n", c.type);
                        Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}\n", c.symbol);
                        Console.WriteLine("Side : {0}\n", c.side);                           
                    }
```

I have two important questions:

1. How can I know whether the JSON returned is only 1 row of Order
   object or a collection so that I can use the relevant way to loop.
2. If it is an array, do I need to deserialize as below and if so, how
   do I add them to Order Class/Object?

   RootObject ord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend you stop using `dynamic` because I think this is an abuse of the type. Instead I would define types to deserialize into. By doing so you give yourself type safety and working with the data becomes trivial. Below are class definitions an example using the generic deserialize method (`Deserialize<T>(string input)`).

```
 public class order
 {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string type { get; set; }
      public string symbol { get; set; }
      public string side { get; set; }
 }

 public class orders
 {
      List<order> order { get; set; }
 }

 JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
 orders myOrders = serializer.Deserialize<orders>(response);

 if (myOrders.order.Count() == 1)
   // we have 1 order
```

Comment: I Agree with you #evanmcdonnal. btw I did the class def..
`public class Rootobject
{
    public Orders orders { get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{
    public Order[] order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string side { get; set; }
}`

Comment: @aceventura yeah, I left out that outer most layer of indirection. Please accept answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: But, how do I check for single/multiple orders? and also I need to map the arraylist to an IEnumerable type of Order object. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @aceventura `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you're good to go there. For checking how many orders there are just use `rootInstance.orders.order.Count()`. If you want you could change `List<order>` to `IEnumerable<order>` or `order[]` but I personally prefer using `List<T>` in most cases.

Comment: Thank You very much #evanmcdonnal. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi #evanmcdonnal, I get an error when I get back only 1 record for order list. 
`"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'GetOrder[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) `

Comment: My request is similar to the below existing request.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118324/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-array-or-object`

Comment: @aceventura in both of your example json blobs you have an array, it's just in the one case it has a single item in it. I believe if your class were to have both a `List<order>` and a plain old `order` after you deserialize with json.NET one would remain null while the other gets instantiated/populated with the json data. You could just check for nullity afterwards or you could use the `object` approach, my only problem with that is that you give up type safety.

Comment: btw if you want me to be alerted by your comments you need to use @userName rather than #userName

Comment: Thank You @evanmcdonnal. Going by the twitter way..;-)

Answer (score 0):

Able to fix the issue pertaining to check if the JSON result returned is an object or an array.
Modified my RootObject which has the Array/Object as follows:

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(GenericListCreationJsonConverter<T>))]
 public List<T> order { get; set; }
```

Added the below class which checks for JSON

```
internal class GenericListCreationJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader);
            }
            else
            {
                T t = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
                return new List<T>(new[] { t });
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```